# Table in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

What is the easyest way in JAVAFX to create a table like that:
[image]

I'm considering using TableView or doing it with HBox and every table cell is it's own rectangle. What would you guys suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you just need a 1 row of with many columns (per image) so a table isn't what I would use. A [ListView](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ListView.html) is basically a 1 dimensional table which is what you are looking for. Using an `ObservableList` as your data model is an easy way to feed data. Modify the list and the `ListView` updates automatically

```
ObservableList<String> model = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
      " ", "X", " ", "X", "X", " ", " ", "X");
listView.setOrientation(Orientation.HORIZONTAL);
ListView<String> listView = new ListView<String>(model);
```

This is a [working example](https://github.com/kevinrandrup/ListViewFXExample) on GitHub:

[image: ListViewFXExample]

Comment: Thank you, i'd love to use that but is there any option to narrow the size of column down so the separator between two colums wouldn't be so large? Currently if you put two X-es or [ ] next to each other there's pretty large gap between

Comment: I don't know offhand, but from the documentation link above, "The visuals of the ListView can be entirely customized by replacing the default cell factory. A cell factory is used to generate ListCell instances, which are used to represent an item in the ListView. See the Cell class documentation for a more complete description of how to write custom Cells."